# Is there a standard component for collapsible panel in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a collapsible side panel similar to the one in Qt Designer (See attached screenshot). They appear to be QListViews placed in some sort of collapsible widget.

[image]

I googled for "Qt collapsible panel" and it seems that there is no standard component for this, or at least not under that name. So, does anyone know whether any standard Qt component has the same behavior? If not, can anyone suggests how I can go about building it?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the behaviour the same as a QTreeView? The top level items being the widgets categories and the bottom level items being the widgets themselves? Perhaps you can subclass a QTreeView and customize the look of top level items and make them expand on single click.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I decided to follow the general approach laid out in the link provided by Joey.

Specifically, I created a widget for each collapsible list. This widget consists of a QPushButton at the top and a QListView at the bottom.

Then, I wired the button clicked signal to a handler to toggle the geometry of the QListView between having height of 0 when it is hidden and its original height when it reappears.

I find that this approach is much simpler compared to customizing the paint event as suggested by Claudio. Furthermore, I can use QAnimationProperty to animate the change in geometry to make the list appear to "slide" in and out of view.

But anyway thanks for the replies!

Comment: Perhaps you wouldn't need to customize the paint event, it might be enough to adjust the display style. For top level items you set centred alignment, different background and a triangle icon pointing downward when they are expanded, and turn off the root decorations. Animations are handled by QTreeView.
The advantage is that you just have to provide a tree model, no matter how many top level items are there. With your solution if you add a category you have to modify your widget, and also your items are spread in multiple views. If this doesn't concern you then your solution should be fine.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into the possibility of customizing a QTreeView. What you described does indeed sound like a more flexible approach. But at the moment I only have need to display items at a single level. My main concern is still how the UI will look. If the QTreeView can produce the desired look and feel I'll go with it. Anyway thanks for the helpful hint!

Answer (score 3):

I created the collapsible panel. Here's the Code:

```
import os
import sys 
from pathlib import Path
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication ,QListWidget, QListView, QLabel, QWidget, QAbstractItemView, QSplitter 
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QIcon, Qt, QDrag
from PySide2 import QtCore

PATH = os.path.join('.','img_src')
print('LayerSelector Loaded with path:' , PATH)

class CustomQStandardItem(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, icon, text):
        super().__init__(icon, text)
    
    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        pass
        
class LayersList(QWidget):
    '''
    LayerList class which acts as collapsable list.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, layers, expand = True):
        super().__init__()
        self.currently_expanded = True
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setMargin(0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.expand_button = QPushButton(name)
        self.expand_button.setToolTip(f"List of {name} Layers")
        self.expand_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(PATH,'LayersList_Up.png')))
        self.layer_list = QListView()
        self.layer_list.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.container_model = QStandardItemModel()
        for l in layers:
            qs = CustomQStandardItem(QIcon(os.path.join(PATH,'LayersList_Layer_Icon.png')),l)
            self.container_model.appendRow(qs)
        self.layer_list.setModel(self.container_model)
        self.layer_list.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.expand_button,0, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.layer_list, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.expand_button.clicked.connect(self.expand)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.resized_size = 16.5 * len(layers)
        self.set_styling()
        if not expand:
            self.expand()
            
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def expand(self):
        if self.currently_expanded:
            self.layer_list.setMaximumHeight(0)
            self.expand_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(PATH,'LayersList_Down.png')))
            self.currently_expanded = False
        else:
            self.layer_list.setMaximumHeight(self.resized_size)
            self.expand_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(PATH,'LayersList_Up.png')))
            self.currently_expanded = True
            
    def set_styling(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:aliceblue ;")
        self.expand_button.setStyleSheet("text-align:left;")
        self.layer_list.setStyleSheet("background-color:aliceblue; border:1px solid;border-style: ridge;")

class LayersSelectorWidget(QWidget):
    '''
    LayerChoiceWidget class provide widget plugin for picking layers.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        names = ['Core Layers',
                 'Convolution Layers',
                 'Pooling Layers',
                 'Recurrent Layers',
                 'Preprocessing Layers',
                 'Attention Layers',
                 'Reshaping Layers',
                 'Locally-Connected Layers'
                 ]
        layers = [
            ['Dense', 'Activation', 'Embedding', 'Masking', 'Lambda'],
            ['Conv1D', 'Conv2D', 'Conv3D', 'SeparableConv1D', 'SeparableConv2D', 'DepthwiseConv2D', 'Conv2DTranspose', 'Conv3Dtranspose'],
            ['MaxPooling1D', 'MaxPooling2D', 'MaxPooling3D', 'AveragePooling1D', 'AveragePooling2D', 'AveragePooling3D', 'GlobalMAxPooling1D', 'GlobalMAxPooling2D', 'GlobalMAxPooling3D', 'GlobalAveragePooling1D', 'GlobalAveragePooling2D', 'GlobalAveragePooling3D'],
            ['LSTM', 'GRU', 'SimpleRNN', 'TimeDistributed', 'BiDirectional', 'ConvLSTM2D'],
            ['TextToVector', 'Normalization'],
            ['Attention', 'AdditiveAttention'],
            ['Reshape', 'Flatten', 'Cropping1D', 'Cropping2D', 'Cropping3D', 'UpSampling1D', 'UpSampling2D', 'UpSampling3D', 'ZeroPadding1D', 'ZeroPadding2D', 'ZeroPadding3D'],
            ['LocallyConnected1D', 'LocallyConnected2D']
        ]
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for i in range(len(names)):
            if i > 3:
                self.main_layout.addWidget(LayersList(names[i], layers[i], False))
            else:
                self.main_layout.addWidget(LayersList(names[i], layers[i]))                
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)        
        self.main_layout.setMargin(0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        del(names)
        del(layers)
        self.set_styling()
        
    def set_styling(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:aliceblue; border:0px solid;border-style: solid;")
```

Below is the result of above Code :

[image: Result]

You can also play with `set_styling` to change look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

> the button clicked signal to a handler to toggle the geometry of the QListView between having height of 0 when it is hidden and its original height when it reappears

For those who are using Qt QML, the [@lightalchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099200) answer can be implemented using the [height](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#height-prop) property with [NumberAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html):

```
// File Section.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Column {
    required property string text
    Button {
        text: parent.text
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            left: parent.left
        }
        onClicked: {
            content.expanded = !content.expanded
        }
    }

    Column {
        id: content
        clip: true
        property bool expanded: true
        height: expanded ? implicitHeight : 0
        Behavior on height {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 200 }
        }
        Slider {}
        Slider {}
    }
}
```

```
// File main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "App"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        Section { text: "First" }
        Section { text: "Second" }
        Section { text: "Third" }
    }
}
```

[image: collapsable items]